# GPU Compute unavailable in wsl2 in new build?

Tags: windows, gpu, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I’m in the windows insider program to utilize the gpu-compute features that were implemented last summer. Things have worked great. However, after updating to the most recent build, nvidia-smi no longer works. I get an error saying “your operating system doesn’t allow it”

https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/04/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21354/

This is the release doc. I’m unsure whether my error is a result of the last bullet point in the known issues section, or if my driver has somehow been corrupted, or if something needs to be toggled back on in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue. Should be resolved in next build. The issue can be tracked here:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6773

Update: It has been resolved as of build 21359

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it not working in this build (21354).
If you have already updated you can try to rollback to the last build.  Go to Settings -> Update&Security -> Recovery and select "Go back to the previous version of Windows 10".